# What is the best way to determine the process noise matrix $\mathbf Q$ of a Kalman filter?

Tags: filters, noise, kalman-filters, matrix

It seems like most of the resources online suggest to determine the values of the process noise matrix $\mathbf Q$ through trial and error. However sometimes trial and error doesn't work, so I would like to know whether there is a way to approximate it e.g. via maths or whatever.

To clarify, I am talking about the matrix $\mathbf Q$ which can be found in the following formula:

$$\mathbf M_k = \mathbf \Phi_k + \mathbf P_{k-1} \mathbf\Phi^T_{k} + \mathbf Q_k$$ Where $\mathbf M_k$ represents the covariance matrix (before an update in this case). I know that 
$$\mathbf Q = E\left[\mathbf w \mathbf w^T\right]$$

where $\mathbf w$ is a white-noise process. Which is part of this classical formula:

$$\dot{\mathbf x} = F\mathbf x + G\mathbf u +\mathbf w$$

But I don't know how to determine $\mathbf w$ neither...
To the people who are familiar with [this very nice book (Fundamentals of Kalman Filtering, Zarchan *et al.*)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1600867189) you can find the former equation on page 131 and the second one on page 129.